# Strange intersection \cap symbol

Tags: symbols

Whenever I use \cap in my tex, I get:
[image]

(which I don't like) instead of:

[image]

Any way to produce the second intersection symbol? The same happens with \cup.

Edit: this is what I always use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,spanish]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{pifont,ulem}
\usepackage{multicol,enumerate,prettyref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareMathOperator{\nullspace}{null}
\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{rango}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re }
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im }
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.2cm,lmargin=2.1cm,rmargin=1.9cm,headheight=0cm,headsep=0cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{nota}{Nota}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observación}

\newrefformat{fig}{la figura \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{teo}{el teorema  \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{lema}{el lema  \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{prop}{la proposici\'on  \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{coro}{el corolario  \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{sec}{la secci\'on \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{cap}{el cap\'{i}tulo \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{def}{la definici\'on  \ref{#1}}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
% comando recta
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

Comment: Erm, what kind of answer do you expect? You are withholding every bit of necessary information...

Comment: I don't know what else to add...

Comment: What do you expect, if I'm asking is because I don't know where is the core of the problem.

Comment: Well, now you've at least added some code we can look at. BTW the problem is the package `mathabx`, which replaces a lot of symbols.

Comment: Right, thanks then.

Comment: @campa That's understatement: `mathabx` changes *all* math symbols and not always in pleasant ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always consider providing a MWE. While doing this you can very often identify the cause for your problem.

Here I did this for you. I set up a document with your default preamble, added a body (`\begin{document} \[ a\cap b\] \end{document}`) and compiled. The problem is reproduced, so it is a *working* example. It remains to make it *minimal*. Therefore delete one package after the other, see if the problem is still there. Like this you get the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\[a\cap b\]
\end{document}
```

Obviously the `mathabx` package is responsible for the redefined symbol.

How can one resolve the problem? We'll store the original definition of `\cap` in `\oldcap`, load `mathabx`, and restore the old `\cap`. You will have to do the same for `\cup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldcap\cap
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\cap\oldcap

\begin{document}
\[a\cap b\bigcup\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]